# Remove stars question from Leetcode (2390)

Tags: c, string, algorithm, function, data-structures

**Problem:**
You are given a string s, which contains stars *.

In one operation, you can:

Choose a star in s.
Remove the closest non-star character to its left, as well as remove the star itself.
Return the string after all stars have been removed.

I have come up with two solutions to this problem. Both of these work on my computer but when I submit on Leetcode, it gives me **heap-buffer-overflow** error. The solutions I made are:

**Solution 1**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* remStars();
char* calc();

int main(){

char* str = "leeet**code*e";

remStars(str);

}

char* remStars(char* s){
    char* newStr = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i = 0;
    strncpy(newStr,s,len);
    int newLen = strlen(newStr);
    for(i=0;i<newLen-1;i++){
        if(newStr[i]=='*'){
          
          newStr= calc(newStr,i,newLen);
          newLen = strlen(newStr);
          i= 0;
        }
        if(newStr[0]!='*' && newStr[1]=='*'){
            newStr = NULL;
        }
        
    }
    printf("The value of newStr is: %s\n", newStr);
    return newStr;
}

char* calc(char*s, int i,int len){
    char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    strncpy(temp,s,i-1);
    for(int j = i+1;j<=(len-1)&& s[j]!= '\0';j++){ 
        strncat(temp, &s[j],1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* removeStars();


int main(){
char* str = "leet**code*e";
removeStars(str);
}

char* removeStars(char* s){
    char* newStr = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
    char* newStr2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
    int i = 0,j=1;
    
    int len = strlen(s);
    newStr =s;
    int newLen = strlen(newStr);
    //newStr2 = s;
    for(i = 0;i<=newLen;i++){
        
        //printf("The new String is: %s\n", newStr);
        if(newStr[i]=='*'){
            strncpy(newStr2,newStr,i-1);
            strncat(newStr2,newStr+i+1,len-i);
         //printf("The str is: %s\n", newStr2);
         newLen = strlen(newStr2);
         newStr = malloc(sizeof(char)*newLen);
         strcpy(newStr,newStr2);
         s = removeStars(newStr);
         break;
        }
        
    
    }
    
    //printf("The s String is: %s\n", s);
return s;
}
```

Comment: You have not nul-terminated the strings copied by `strncpy`. *If `count` is less than or equal to the length of `strSource`, a null character isn't appended automatically to the copied string.* But anyway, 10 bytes or 12 bytes allocation isn't enough to copy `"leeet**code*e"` into.

Comment: Also the [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/removing-stars-from-a-string/) says `1 <= s.length <= 100000`. Always test your code to the limits given.

Comment: Hello @WeatherVane, Thank you for your quick response. I am not sure if I understood your first comment. However, as for the second comment, I changed the size of bytes to the size of the string. So now I have, "char* newStr = malloc(sizeof(char)*stringLength)" but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: What it means, is that if you copy up to `n` characters of a string which has length `n` or more, then no nul-terminator is added. However, all this string copying might fail the problem time limit. There is no need to do any string copying. If you parse the string working with two indexes, say `getindex` and `putindex` you can just decrease `putindex` when you read a star from `getindex` (watch out for underflow), or otherwise copy one character from `getindex` to `putindex`. I'll leave the finer details to you, but don't forget to nul-terminate the shortened string before printing.

Comment: Hello @WeatherVane, Thank you for your help!! I did try out the solutions that you had guided me too. They were successful. Also, I had to change the parameter in the removeStars method to Char array instead of pointer inside main function. As that was giving me bus error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, including:

- `malloc(sizeof(char)*10);` or `malloc(sizeof(char)*12);` is not allocating enough space in general as the input string can be much longer than that.
- `newStr= calc(newStr,i,newLen);` leaks memory: the originally allocated `newStr` memory is not freed, and you lost the reference to it. Same issue with `newStr = malloc(sizeof(char)*newLen);`
- `newStr = NULL;` prepares a disaster in the next iteration when `newStr[i]` is accessed -- an invalid reference.

The thing is that you don't need to allocate memory for a new string at all. You can use the memory of the *input* string.

Here is an algorithm:

- Iterate the characters from start to end, and use two index variables, one to copy *from* and one to copy *to*. They both start at 1.

  - If the character is not a asterisk, then copy it and increase both indexes.
  - Otherwise increase the leading index, and *decrease* the lagging index (since the character that is there -- possibly copied there -- must be considered erased).
- Make sure to also copy the terminating `\0` character.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
char * removeStars(char * s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (s[i] != '*') {
            s[j++] = s[i];
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Hello @trincot Thank you for your help!! I did try out the solutions that you had guided me too. They were successful. Also, I had to change the parameter in the removeStars method to Char array instead of pointer inside main function. As that was giving me bus error.